# Getting Segmentation fault when installing my RPM trough another RPM requirement

Tags: rpm, segmentation-fault

I have a RPM to install SWFtools as [written here](https://designbye.wordpress.com/2010/02/23/installing-swftools-and-pdf2swf-on-ubuntu-linux/). I have a another RPM that I created containing basic applications, shared to all of our servers. the first RPM (SWFtools) should be installed after the basic RPM.

If I install them one by one, the server work as it's suppose to, but if i'm building the the seconds RPM so the basic RPM will be one of it's requirement so it will be installed automatically, I get segmentation fault while running the `pdf2swf` command.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running this command in the first line of the second RPM `%install` section made it work:

```
 ranlib /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.a
 ldconfig /usr/local/lib
```